# Special Character filtering with null in talend

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, talend, tmap

I have an excel which has few fields. I want to extract only those fields which has a special character **?** in the values. I tried with the **contains** method in tmap without putting in condition for null but I am getting this NullPointer Exception as the fields also contain blank values in those fields.

Here are the excel file :

[image]

Here is the tmap filtering : 
[image]

Here is the error screen :

[image]

Comment: Is the target column nullable? i.e, Is the field in which you are trying to store the output of this expression nullable?

Comment: The target is nullable. The TMAP just had row1.Global_Description.contains("?")||row1.Lead_Product_Segment.contains("?"). I was getting a NullPointerException due to this..And so I was trying to handle null in here but the syntax isn't proper.. how can we handle null in this statement?

Comment: See revised answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One or both of the fields in your expression builder has a null in it. You must check for null before performing string contains. Otherwise it will get a null pointer exception

The below expression will produce a Boolean value of true or false. You can use this expression to filter which rows go onto the output of the tMap

(row1.Global_Description!=null &&
row1.Global_Description.contains("?"))||
(row1.Lead_Product_Segment!=null &&
row1.Lead_Product_Segment.contains("?"))

Comment: The target is nullable. The TMAP just had row1.Global_Description.contains("?")||row1.Lead_Product_Segment.contains("?"). I was getting a NullPointerException due to this..And so I was trying to handle null in here but the syntax isn't proper.. how can we handle null in this statement?